# JavaScript or Ajax with PHP variable session store

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to build online webstore for custom shoes like this site **`http://www.shoesofprey.com/3d/designer?p=20600P4`**

First, people choose what style they want, and then they chose what color they want.  I need to build a script like that (without add to cart).

I think that whatever they click is stored as a session and then from that session a php script picks a image.

Here is what I have done, but it still doesn't work:

**in index.php**

```
    <script language='javascript'>
    function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }       
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getpic(strURL) {       
        var req = getXMLHTTP();
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                            document.getElementById('getimg').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using   XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    }

function createRequestObject() {
     var ro;     
     ro = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();

     return ro;
}

    var http = createRequestObject();

    function sndReq(action) {
     http.open('get', 'rpc.php?action='+action);
     http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
     http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() {
     if(http.readyState == 4){
          var response = http.responseText;
          var update = new Array();

          if(response.indexOf('|') != -1) {
               update = response.split('|');
               document.getElementById(update[0]).innerHTML = update[1];
          }
     }
}
    </script>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:sndReq('top')">[TOP]</a>
            <a href="javascript:sndReq('bottom')">[BOTTOM]</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="getimg" style="width:600px;height:450px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:10px;">
                <img src="img/polos.jpg">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="foo">
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="black"> black </label><br/><br/>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="blue"> blue </label><br/><br/>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="brown"> brown </label><br/><br/>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="red"> red </label><br/><br/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

**in rpc.php**

```
switch($_REQUEST['action']) {
     case 'top':
          /* do something */
          session_start();
          // store session data
          $_SESSION['top']="t";

          echo "foo|"?>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="1" onChange="getpic('http://localhost/distrokl/img.php?tcl='+this.value)"> blue </label><br/><br/>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="2" onChange="getpic('http://localhost/distrokl/img.php?tcl='+this.value)"> brown </label><br/><br/>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="3" onChange="getpic('http://localhost/distrokl/img.php?tcl='+this.value)"> red </label><br/><br/>
          <?;
          break;

    case 'bottom':
          /* do something */
          session_start();
          // store session data
          $_SESSION['bottom']="b";

          echo "foo|"?>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="1" onChange="getpic('http://localhost/distrokl/img.php?bcl='+this.value)"> blue </label><br/><br/>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="2" onChange="getpic('http://localhost/distrokl/img.php?bcl='+this.value)"> brown </label><br/><br/>
            <label><input name="color" type="radio" value="3" onChange="getpic('http://localhost/distrokl/img.php?bcl='+this.value)"> red </label><br/><br/>
          <?;
          break;
}

**and in img.php**

    session_start();
    $tcl = $_REQUEST['tcl'];
    $_SESSION['tcl']=$tcl;

    $bcl = $_REQUEST['bcl'];
    $_SESSION['bcl']=$bcl;

    $top = $_SESSION['top'];
    $bottom = $_SESSION['bottom'];

    $topcl = $_SESSION['tcl'];
    $botcl = $_SESSION['bcl'];

                echo "<img src='img/".$top.$topcl.$bottom.$botcl".jpg'><br/>";
```

Any ideas on what I need to do?

Comment: You could try using jQuery. It would simplify your code a lot.

Comment: can you please give me some sample? or maybe some link for e to learn that

Comment: Tutorial - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: ok, thx a lot aspirin for link, i'll try that,

Comment: ok, i have done what i need, using javascript, should i put my code here?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=jquery+tutorials

Comment: Please post your answer